# How to disable auto suspend in Ubuntu LTE server using terminal

Tags: command-line, server, suspend, configuration

I’m currently having a home Ubuntu server, and after not using it for an hour it suspends. How can I disable that using command line? What is the config file and what should I change.

Comment: Is it `LTE` or `LTS` and which version?

Comment: ‘LTS’ version. 18.04